# Laravel migration: drop specific table and remove migration file using artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-artisan

I have been working using Laravel. I was thinking about this problem. Is it possible to drop a specific table and remove migration file using just a artisan command?

I know there are couple of ways to do these job like `Schema::drop('')` or creating new migration etc. I am just curious to find such artisan command to do these job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this in one command without writing your own artisan command (`artisan make:command`) - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan#writing-commands

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom artisan command.

```
artisan make:command
```